# Get timestamp for hour of current day

Tags: python, python-datetime

Ok, I need a way to get the timestamp for the current day but at a certain time.

So for example, I want the unix timestamp for today at 7:30PM - what would I do to get that value? In PHP it's possible with the strtotime() but I'm not sure how to do this in Python.

Edit: To clarify, I mean the current day **not** a statically written day. So if I ran this script tomorrow it would return the timestamp for 7:30PM tomorrow.

Comment: A UNIX timestamp isn't all that useful; is that actually what you need or do you need to do more with that timestamp once you have it?

Comment: The timestamp is all I need, it gets converted to various string formats later in the program. But the UNIX timestamp is good for a standard format.

Comment: I disagree. Within one Python program a `datetime` object is far more flexible and versatile. Just like `unicode` is the better and more versatile object type for text, you want to use the best representation throughout your code, parse into that type as early as possible, and only convert to output formats at the last possible moment.

Comment: That's a fair point, I would be fine doing that (the format doesn't matter to me, I just need to accomplish what I've stated in my question).

Comment: You can always use `datetime.time(19, 30)` to get a time object representing 7:30PM, then combine that with `datetime.date.today()`, for example, using `datetime.datetime.combine()`. Or use `datetime.datetime.now().replace(hour=19, minute=30)` to get the same result.

Answer (score 1):

```
from datetime import datetime

now = datetime.utcnow() # Current time
then = datetime(1970,1,1) # 0 epoch time
ts = now - then

ts = ts.days * 24 * 3600 + ts.seconds
# alternatively, per Martijn Pieters
ts = int(ts.total_seconds())
```

Comment: There is a `ts.total_seconds()` method that is much more helpful here.

Comment: Nifty, didn't know about that. I'll toss it in.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the time module  :

```
from datetime import datetime   
from time import mktime
# like said Ashoka
ts = datetime.strptime("2014-7-7 7:30","%Y-%m-%d %H:%M")
#you have now your datetime object
print mktime(ts.timetuple())
# print 1404711000.0
print int(mktime(ts.timetuple()))
# print 1404711000
```

be careful mktime don't care of time zone so if you want to have a UTC time zone and still use time , convert date before:

```
import pytz
fr = pytz.timezone('Europe/Paris')
#localize
ts = fr.localize(ts)
#timestamp in UTC
mktime(ts.astimezone(pytz.UTC).timetuple())
```

Comment: `mktime` returns a local time timestamp. You should use `calendar.timegm(datetime.utctimetuple())`.

Comment: humm i'm not shure , let me check but i think that return UTC timestamps if you specify tz to datetime

Comment: It doesn't matter. The time tuple does not contain time zone info, only whether it is DST or not. [time.struct_time](https://docs.python.org/2/library/time.html#time.struct_time)

Comment: you're right, that's return in the TZ of the datetime, you can specified tz , let's me edit

Comment: This still does not work. It returns a local timestamp. `datetime.utcfromtimestamp(mktime(ts.astimezone(pytz.UTC).timetuple()))` returns `datetime.datetime(2014, 7, 7, 4, 30)`

Comment: @kroolik: `datetime.timetuple()` **also** returns a value in the local timezone, so in the end the offset is the exact same as when using `datetime.utctimetuple()` and `calendar.timegm()`

Comment: @MartijnPieters, yes, what I'm saying is that `.timetuple()` does not work for aware datetimes - they will yield wrong timestamp, which is not in UTC.

Comment: @kroolik: But the base datetime is only aware if you explicitly ask for one. Until Python 3.2 the `datetime` module doesn't even come with timezones bundled. In my experience anyone working with timestamps are not being too picky about timezones anyway. As such, it's just a caveat that needs qualifying; e.g. *unless you are working with naive datetime objects, you want to use the UTC timetuple*, or words to that effect.

Comment: @MartijnPieters, you are right. What I was trying to achieve is the most general solution for the OP's problem as there was no mention about awareness, and the regular `mktime` solution would lead to incorrect stamps with aware datetimes.

Answer (score 0):

[calendar.timegm](https://docs.python.org/2/library/calendar.html#calendar.timegm) method returns a timestamp out of passed time tuple:

```
import calendar
from datetime import datetime

d = datetime(year=2014, month=7, day=8, hour=7, minute=30)
calendar.timegm(d.utctimetuple())
# 1404804600

datetime.utcfromtimestamp(calendar.timegm(d.utctimetuple()))
# datetime.datetime(2014, 7, 8, 7, 30)
```

The important things are `utctimetuple` and `utcfromtimestamp`. You would certainly want a UTC timestamp, and not one in your local timezone.

```
import calendar
from datetime import datetime
from pytz import timezone, utc

tz = timezone('Europe/Warsaw')
aware = datetime(year=2014, month=7, day=8, hour=7, minute=30)
aware = tz.localize(aware)
# datetime.datetime(2014, 7, 8, 7, 30, tzinfo=<DstTzInfo 'Europe/Warsaw' CEST+2:00:00 DST>)

stamp = calendar.timegm(aware.utctimetuple())
# 1404797400

d = datetime.utcfromtimestamp(stamp)
# datetime.datetime(2014, 7, 8, 5, 30)

d = d.replace(tzinfo=utc)
d.astimezone(tz)
# datetime.datetime(2014, 7, 8, 7, 30, tzinfo=<DstTzInfo 'Europe/Warsaw' CEST+2:00:00 DST>)
```

Comment: Yet `time.mktime(d.timetuple())` gives the exact same timestamp because for a naive datetime object both operate in the same timezone.

Comment: @MartijnPieters, yes, but naive datetimes are not the only types of objects

Comment: Sure, only when you actually add in a timezone is `utctimetuple()` important. But that's an *important nuance*, you didn't mention that in the other comments.

Comment: @MartijnPieters, also, `mktime` takes into account local timezone thus it further modifies the output timestamp (according to that timezone). `calendar.timegm` on the other hand just takes in timetuple and returns timestamp for that particular spot in time.